# 400: bad request

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I'm using csmanage to access the Azure Management API. This is my code:

```
    private const string subscriberID = "<id>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The thumbprint value of the management certificate.
        // You must replace the string with the thumbprint of a 
        // management certificate associated with your subscription.
        string certThumbprint = "<thumbprint>";

        // Create a reference to the My certificate store.
        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        // Try to open the store.
        try
        {
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }

        // Find the certificate that matches the thumbprint.
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbprint, false);
        certStore.Close();

        // Check to see if our certificate was added to the collection. If no, throw an error, if yes, create a certificate using it.
        if (0 == certCollection.Count)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: No certificate found containing thumbprint " + certThumbprint);
        }

        // Create an X509Certificate2 object using our matching certificate.
        X509Certificate2 certificate = certCollection[0];



        var serviceManagment = ServiceManagementHelper.CreateServiceManagementChannel("WindowsAzureEndPoint", new X509Certificate2(certificate));
        var x = serviceManagment.ListHostedServices(subscriberID);

        foreach (HostedService s in x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.ServiceName);
        }
    }
```

This works fine in a console application. However, when I execute the exact same code in a WCF project (as a service implementation) I'm getting `400 - Bad Request` as a result.

What could cause this error?

Comment: try using fiddler to track the requests and responses - both from Console App and form WCF Service app, check the difference in requests.

Comment: I've used fiddler already. Can't find any diffences at all..

Comment: And how about the responses? The 400 response details in fiddler shall be a bit more specific (sometimes they are..) Probably if you paste the Request/Response pairs for both the requests we might be able to help more. Use the `Raw` section in fiddler to get the raw data from request and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really an answer but one thing you could do is see more details about 400 error by catching the web exception using code similar to the following:

```
    catch (WebException webEx)
    {
        string errorDetail = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(webEx.Response.GetResponseStream(), true))
        {
            errorDetail = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Here `errorDetail` will be an XML that should give you more information.

Comment: yep, and Azure Management service tend to give some data on the various errors, which can only be seen by (1) Fiddler or (2) the method Gaurav explains.

Comment: Traverse the InnerException. Somewhere down the line you would find an exception of type WebException.

Comment: There's indeed a WebException, but there's no more information in it other than "Bad Request"...

Comment: First, I was able to reproduce the issue you're facing. Not really a WCF expert, but I noticed a weird thing: For some reason, the request sent to Windows Azure is a "POST" request instead of a "GET" request when sent through WCF service. The request is sent as a "GET" request (which is correct) through the console app. I believe you're getting this error because of that only. Hope this gives you some idea.

Comment: Thanks, how did you find that? Any clue how I might be able to solve it?

Comment: I traced the request through Fiddler and saw the details there. I spent quite a few hours yesterday trying to solve this but given my lack of knowledge with WCF, nothing came out of it :(. Sorry! Will give it a try again today. Can you share the complete code for your WCF Service? You could possibly upload the entire project somewhere so that I can download it and play with that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27006/discussion-between-bv202-and-gaurav-mantri)